# Would APC work well for a highly dynamic PHP website?

Tags: php, apache, apc

This might be a trivial question for some, but I could not find the answer myself yet.

If I understand correctly APC does two things. Keep the PHP pages in byte code so they are delivered faster. It can also cache data so we can query them faster.

I'm interested in the byte code feature, which if I understand correctly comes by default. I will not need to modify my code much for this to work.

My question is this: Our website is a social network site and our PHP pages are highly dynamic. They are affected by many factors every time they are called.

Would we still benefit from using APC?

Thanks,
Haluk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is exactly the type of situation that APC works great in (although it benefits all types of pages). It's essentially a "compiler" for PHP code.

Unless the PHP code behind is changing more often than the page is loaded (I don't think that would EVER happen), APC will benefit you.

For any static pages (or static parts of pages), you might want to look into caching the output to files on the system. That way, when you need to display that component, instead of running PHP code you can just serve up the cached HTML.

Comment: Okay I think I'm starting to understand. This similar to keeping Java in byte-code. Okay. Now I see.

Answer (score 1):

It wont work so well for the dynamic parts of your website, unless you cache them individually, but you will benefit from the bytecode cache without any changes to your code

Further reading

- http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/10/07/understanding-apc/
- http://devzone.zend.com/article/12618-Using-APC-with-PHP

Comment: The "Understanding APC" article referenced above says: "If you have a small application under a lot of load, then APC is a good choice." I do not exactly understand this. What is a small application? Is this referring to the number of PHP pages we have, in our case we have a few hundred PHP pages. I would consider it small. Considering we are working on one server and we do not need distributed caching and APC is easier to maintain. I'm thinking APC is a good fit for us. And actually I'm starting to think why isn't APC a default option for PHP if it is this good.

Comment: @Haluk APC will be included in PHP core in PHP.next. Since installing it now is not much of an effort, I suggest you just give it a try and bench with a tool like ab or siege to see if your app benefits from it. I predict it will.